# How to remove the default Search Verticals in Search Center using PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, search-center

I need to write a PowerShell to remove all the default Search Verticals that's created in SP 2013's Ent.Search Center.
Because I don't want to show `Everything`, `Videos`,`Conversations`,`People` below my Search Center's search box.

Comment: The links to the verticals or the pages?

Comment: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/choroshin/2014/05/11/sharepoint-2013-add-and-remove-items-from-search-navigation-using-powershell/

Comment: I mean, the links only.

Comment: For the links, take a look at the link above.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into this.My doubt is why we need to iterate through each and every sub sites in the site collection.

Comment: The script iterate through all subsites. :)

Comment: You still want to create a test search enterprise center to test this.

Comment: Why not just delete the web part?